# Return data with pivot field Laravel Api

Tags: laravel, pivot, eloquent-relationship

I want to return a role with permissions of it through pivot table, relationship, but when I write:

```
$role = $this->roleRepository->detail($id);
    $data = ([
        "role" => $role
    ]);
```

postman just return:

```
"data": {
        "role": {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "grand-admin"
        }
    }
```

I write:

```
        $role = $this->roleRepository->detail($id);
        $data = ([
            "role" => $role,
            "hasPermission" => $role->permissions
        ]);
```

Postman return:

```
"data": {
        "role": {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "grand-admin",
            "permissions": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "view_customer",
                    "pivot": {
                        "role_id": 12,
                        "permission_id": 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "view_customer",
                    "pivot": {
                        "role_id": 12,
                        "permission_id": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "hasPermission": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "view_customer",
                "pivot": {
                    "role_id": 12,
                    "permission_id": 1
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "view_customer",
                "pivot": {
                    "role_id": 12,
                    "permission_id": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Problem is loop 2 times data of permission, how can I write to return only the upper part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either include the relationship in the repository logic (using `with`), or you can lazy-load the relationship like so:

```
$role = $this->roleRepository->detail($id);
$role->load('permissions');
$data = ([
    "role" => $role
]);
```

Lazy loading reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading

OR

you can include `permissions` as a default loading relationship by defining the `$with` property in the model:

```
//your role model
class Role extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['permissions'];
...
}
```

Now your existing code should include permissions.

Default loading reference: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default

Comment: Thank you, 'load' is key method, i couldn't think of it, try method 'with' but it is not operate haha